# Sull'incidenza delle virgole parentetiche nella declinazione del verbo

Tags: verbs

Nello scrivere un metapost mi sono chiesto se questa frase

> Dispiace davvero tanto, lui (o lei), con @DaG e pochi altri, ha dato al sito un grandissimo contributo di qualità in questo primo - e forse ultimo - anno di vita.

fosse corretta circa l'uso di 'ha' piuttosto che di 'hanno'.

Nella risposta si noti che 'con @DaG e pochi altri' è fra le virgole, che se così non fosse stato certamente avrei scritto 'hanno' lì.

Quindi, qual è la risposta, 'ha' o 'hanno'?

E come cambia, se cambia, la risposta se avessi scritto

> Dispiace davvero tanto, lui (o lei) - con @DaG e pochi altri - ha dato al sito un grandissimo contributo di qualità in questo primo - e forse ultimo - anno di vita.

cioè sostituendo le virgole parentetiche con i trattini?

Answer (score 7):

In ciascuno dei casi che citi in realtà è corretto utilizzare "ha".

> A con B e C ha dato un contributo.
>
> A, con B e C, ha dato un contributo.
>
> A -- con B e C -- ha dato un contributo.

In ogni caso il soggetto è sempre e solo A. Gli altri due, B e C, stanno sempre nel complemento e quindi non partecipano a formare il numero del soggetto. Il verbo si coniuga in numero solo con il soggetto. Devo però anche aggiungere che secondo me le virgole (o i trattini) sono piuttosto consigliate in questa frase; la prima variante che propongo è un po' poco leggibile, per quanto grammaticalmente corretta.

Sarebbe invece diverso il caso:

> A, B e C hanno dato un contributo.

In questo caso tutti e tre sono soggetti, quindi danno un numero plurale.